# Replicate output of pwm pin on another output pin?

Tags: arduino-mega, pwm, analogwrite, digitalwrite

Ardiuno Mega 2560

I have a legacy PCB that connects PORTA, pins = {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29} to the PWM input of a set of actuators. The accompanying code made use of an interupt service routine to generate PWM signals. This in turn caused all sorts of other problems for the system.

So, I would like to leverage the Mega's internal counters & use the PWM available on pins = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} & use the `analogWrite()` function. At present there is nothing else connected to these pins but access is limited.

Before I go down the route of redesigning the PCB I was wondering if it was possible to replicate the outputs of pins {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} to pins {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}?

Comment: It is not clear, what you are trying to achieve. What I understood is: You want do measure the value of the PWM signal on the pins {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29} and then outputting a new PWM signal with the same value on the pins {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}. Is that correct?

Comment: I want to generate the PWM on pins {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} using analogWrite() but replicate that output on pins {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}

Comment: It is not possible to route pins to other pins, the functionality of a pin is fixed to that pin. You could try a software pwm library.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you want the same PWM signal on more than 1 pin? Why don't you just connect the one pin to both targets?

Comment: as mentioned in the orginal post the issue is to do with a legacy PCB. I'm just soundng out options before I have to redesign anything

Comment: Internally, it's not possible. If pins 22 through 29 are not used for anything else, soldering jumper wires onto a spacer or directly onto the PCB might be an option.
Otherwise, as @Jot suggested, software PWM is always an option, but they achievable frequency would be limited.

Answer (score 1):

As Jot wrote, you cannot simply route a signal from pin to pin inside the chip/Arduino. So - unless you redesign the PCP, which would be the cleanest way, or use jumper wires, which is not so clean - you are down to using software PWM. There are also libraries for this, if you don't want to write this yourself, for example the [SoftPWM library](https://github.com/bhagman/SoftPWM). These libraries have their own limits, especially in frequency. Be sure to check, if they fit your needs.

Comment: will check out the linked library tomorrow thanks. Is there any reason you can think of why I couldnt hard wire the pins together?

Comment: You can. This is only about how clean the solution would be. Of course it is best to have a PCB thats designed for it. Connecting the pins with jumper wires is a bit less clean, but will work well (as long, as you don't need these pins for other purposes)